# ruby on rails 3 strip html whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-parsing, trim, strip

was:

```
<table >
  <tbody   >
    <tr   >
      <td valign="..."     style="..." >
      ...
```

client should obtain: (you dont need any whitespace in view's output!)

```
<table><tbody><tr><td valign="..." style="">...
```

what is **rails 3** way to do this **without bicycles**?

Comment: Is this in your templates or in user-entered content?

Comment: in my templates. user-generated html should go through sanitize before applying such strip

Comment: if this is in your templates you should fix these issues in your editor, if you're looking for a way to automate this you're asking the wrong question

Comment: Would HAML produce a cleaner markup?  I honestly wouldn't care.  If it's valid, it's valid.  Generated markup is never going to look as clean as hand-written markup.  But if it's valid, then I'm happy.

Comment: you dont understand. in views you have **pretty formatted** code. but in view **output** you don't need whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an aesthetic issue, and doesn't have any effect on browser rendering. If you're worried about "minimizing the page size", this would not give you any noticeable changes (and would cost you server power to cleanup the output on every single request). Enabling server gzip compression would be a far better option.

However, if you are sure you want to do this, then checkout [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 for just using gzip compression if this is a bandwidth thing.  If it's an aesthetic thing, just use HAML.

Comment: standart project page: without gzip: +10%, gzip level 9: 2%. stripping html, minifing css and javascript is a simple way to make your site lighter. aesthetics here is not to blame

Comment: Gzipping alone should provide you with about 70% size reduction (source: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip). Try the "asset packager" plugin to minify your css and js. This will *tremendously* help you in making your site lighter.

Comment: you shoul think and read man before commenting. i have written: **without gzip: +10%**. it means size of my html page is 100%. stipped - 110%. i said nothing about difference between ungzipped and gzipped. dont let me obvious things

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HAML, you can specify option `:ugly` to instruct it to not indent your generated html.

More informations in [documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options).

Id don't know about any setting for erb, but from my understanding, erb doesn't format your code, you format if. If you want to not indent your html, you should write it as such (or preprocess your erb templates before deploying)